# Find Package with source parameter is not working to get the current versions of all the nuget packages

Tags: asp.net, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-explorer, nuget-console

Find Package with source parameter is not working to get the current versions of all the nuget packages

Find-Package -Source "`C:\Users\P10410559\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\packages.config`"

**Error getting as** :

```
Find-Package : The following source failed to search for packages: 'C:\Users\P10410559\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\packages.config'
The path 'C:\Users\P10410559\source\repos\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\packages.config' for the selected source could not be resolved.
At line:1 char:1
+ Find-Package -Source "C:\Users\P10410559\source\repos\WebApplication4 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Find-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.FindPackageCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to search for packages inside a packages.config, which is incorrect for the following reasons -

1. Packages.Config is a file which is stored along with your project to track the packages that you have referenced. The file is not a package source. You can read more about the file [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/packages-config).
2. If you want to find packages then you need to pass a real source like nuget.org to the command. You can read more about the find package command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-find-package). E.g. -

`Find-Package nuget.versioning -Source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`
[image: example snapshot]

If you want to get current version of all packages installed to your project you need to use the Get-Package command described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/ps-ref-get-package). E.g. -

`Get-Package -ProjectName NuGet.Versioning`
[image]